# Append element inside an element on top of other elements inside

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to append an element right inside span element being on top of the parent span from other content?

html

```
<span id="parent">
    <!-- I want the oldest placed here when something is click -->
    <span id="child1">sample1</span>
    <span id="child2">sample2</span>
    <span id="child3">sample3</span>
<span> 

 <button id="write_IT">Put the older!</button>
<!--
     //from php database

     <span id="oldest">
         Test
     </span>
-->
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#write_IT', function(e) {

    var apb = $("#parent").after("<span id='parent'>");
    apb.append('<span id="oldest">Test</span>');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prepend`

```js
$('#write_IT').on("click", function(){
  $("#parent").prepend('<span id="oldest">Test</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parent">
    <!-- I want the oldest placed here when something is click -->
    <span id="child1">sample1</span>
    <span id="child2">sample2</span>
    <span id="child3">sample3</span>
<span> 

<button id="write_IT">Put the older!</button>
```

Comment: That's it, thanks, for that ('Prepend") I have so much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#write_IT', function(e) {

    $("#child1").before('<span id="oldest">Test</span>');

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parent">
    <!-- I want the oldest placed here when something is click -->
    <span id="child1">sample1</span>
<span id="child2">sample2</span>
<span id="child3">sample3</span>
<span> 

 <button id="write_IT">Put the older!</button>
<!--
     //from php database

     <span id="oldest">
         Test
     </span>
-->
```

Use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.